# Why isn't the image added in the block settings shown in the front end?

Tags: blocks

When I try to add a background image in *Bootstrap block settings* (the settings added by the BB Animation Module) Drupal uploads it, but the image doesn't appear on the front end.

[image]

Any help about this?

Comment: I dug through the code and printed the variable array.For all images, it is returning as Array ( [fid] => 313 ) but for the block, the image file id is coming as string (eg: 313)

Comment: This issue is due to the update of Drupal API and Media module. I reverted and checked on my local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I applied a patch for this module. This got disturbed due to the media module update.

At line no 300 in bb_animation.module.I changed the code

from

```
$file = file_load($background_image['fid']);
```

To

```
$background_image_data_type = gettype($background_image);
switch ($background_image_data_type) {
        case 'array':
            $file = file_load($background_image['fid']);
            break;
        case 'string':
            $file = file_load($background_image);
            break;
    }
```